# What and when should I specify setFetchSize()?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, jdbc

I see a lot of "best practices" guides for JDBC/MySQL that tells me to specify setFetchSize().

However, I have no idea when to specify, and what(statement, result set) to specify.

```
Statement.setFetchSize() or PreparedStatement.setFetchSize() 
ResultSet.setFetchSize()
```

1. Of these two, what should I specify?
2. From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#setFetchSize%28int%29) and [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28621), this is where I get confused about "when"

Javadoc

> The default value is set by the Statement object that created the result set. The fetch size may be changed at any time.

Oracle Doc

> Changes made to the fetch size of a statement object after a result set is produced will have no affect on that result set.

Please correct me if I am wrong. Does this mean that setFetchSize is only Affective before a query is executed?(Therefore, setFetchSize on a ResultSet is useless? But happens to "The fetch size may be changed at any time"?)

Comment: The second link is for the Oracle JDBC driver (i.e. for the Oracle *database*), not a "general" JDBC documentation - especially *not* for MySQL. You should check the MySQL JDBC manual for details on that implementation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for pointing that out. It was a obvious thing I should have checked first...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/resltse5.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) from the official docs on *result sets*. It says

> By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in memory. In most cases this is the most efficient way to operate, and due to the design of the MySQL network protocol is easier to implement. If you are working with ResultSets that have a large number of rows or large values, and cannot allocate heap space in your JVM for the memory required, you can tell the driver to stream the results back one row at a time.

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                            java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

> The combination of a forward-only, read-only result set, with a fetch size of Integer.MIN_VALUE serves as a signal to the driver to stream result sets row-by-row. After this, any result sets created with the statement will be retrieved row-by-row.

In effect, setting only fetchSize have no effect on the connector-j implementation.

Comment: This is only for MySQL, most other databases and JDBC drivers behave better than this.

Comment: True, however, the question was about, at least in part, MySQL.

Comment: As the question also referred to Oracle documentation I took it as a general JDBC question; this is one of my pet peeves about the MySQL Connector/J implementation... :)

Comment: After wasting some time trying alternatives, I can confirm that Connector/J really does only support either returning the entire result set, or streaming them one at a time.  I was hoping to return batches of 10,000 but the source code specifically checks for Integer.MIN_VALUE and returns everything if any other value specified.

For anyone using JDBI (http://jdbi.org/), adding the fetch size to your query is sufficient as the other flags are already at the correct values:

handle.createQuery(sql)
  .setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
  .map()/fold() etc

Comment: This is (no longer) true; when setting the JDBC option `useServerFetch`, MySQL actually supports any positive fetch size. However, there are some caveats; see my response to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36986532/1016939

Comment: @lxgr did you mean to write `useCursorFetch` instead of `useServerFetch`?

Comment: @MattBall You're right, that's what it is actually called.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good article with **examples** to your question:

https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-resultset

7.1. Using Fetch Size on Statement
7.2. Using Fetch Size on ResultSet