# Is there a mysql JDBC that will respect fetchSize?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am using MySQL and want to utilize the `setFetchSize` property. The default MySQL JDBC implementation does not really respect it.  If you set fetchsize to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` it will fetch each row individually, but considering the reason I want to use fetchSize is that I have enough data to put my memory usage into the 2 G range having to do one query per row is going to take forever.

I would like to instead plug in a JDBC implementation that will work with MySQL and properly respects fetch size, allowing me to set a fetchsize of 10,000 or some other higher limit.  Can anyone point me to a jar that may provide such an implementation?  failing that is there *any* other resource to allow me to reasonable do a query containing tens of thousands of entries in a manner that is efficient, but in memory and number of sql queries required.

Comment: Integer.MIN_VALUE is negative, how would it fetch some negative number of rows?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That is how the MySQL JDBC driver works. It either fetches (streams) everything or it allows 1-by-1 retrieval when you specify `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html (under ResultSet)

Comment: _"having to do one query per row"_ am I right to understand that you think that fetchSize governs the maximum nr of rows retrieved? Because that is not what happens: a single query will still produce all rows, it will just fetch the rows one-by-one.

Comment: @mark you are correct, it is only one query.  The latency and bandwidth cost of having to ping the server for each row is still what i"m concerned about.  Sorry for not being more precise in my description.

Comment: There is really no ping, or roundtrip, per row (as the unfortunate wording of the MySQL doc might imply).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Technically questions asking for libraries are off-topic. That said, as far as I know there is no alternative driver for MySQL. You either have the choice between getting all rows which might lead to out of memory situations, or to have the driver fetch them on demand by setting `setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)`.

The reason for this - as I understand from the [Connector/J implementation notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) - is that the MySQL protocol cannot have more than one cursor open per connection, therefor it defaults to streaming all rows to the client on execute.

The other option is that rows are retrieved one-by-one, but this comes with the problem that you cannot execute other statements on the same connection while processing the `ResultSet`:

> There are some caveats with this approach. You **must read all** of the rows in the result set (or close it) **before** you can issue **any other queries** on the connection, or an exception will be thrown.

So the MySQL only has the option to get everything or to get one at a time. This means that there is no way for a driver to respect a different fetch size. And due to the caveats when getting one-by-one they opted to use the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (instead of simply `1`) as a signal that you should really think before doing this.

A possible 'in-between' solution would require you to program this yourself using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` and repeatedly executing queries.

Comment: thank you.  I had figured there was a decent chance this was a limitation on the DB itself, but I appreciate your confirming it.  I am, however, surprised someone hasn't made a wrapper that set LIMIT and OFFSET and did the queries behind the scenes for you to mimic setFetchSize intended behavior.  I know it's not quite the same thing, but one could document the difference and advantages/tradoffs of such a wrapper in the javadoc.

Comment: With LIMIT/OFFSET you will execute your query multiple times, potentially giving you wrong results (repeated rows, skipping other rows), unless you LOCK TABLES for READ until ResultSet  is closed, and then UNLOCK them. Quite expensive, the implementation would not be easy (one would need to parse the query to know which tables are involved), so it is not a good idea. Alternatively, you can CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS SELECT..., and read with LIMIT/OFFSET, however this is prone to phantom reads, and again expensive. setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE) is the best alternative for large reads

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub That is a trade off. Actually I might need to update this answer, as I believe that MySQL made some changes and with the right config you can actually use a fetch size other than 1 or all.

Comment: I tested the basic example with `setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` and contrary to the official documentation is NOT done "one row by one", but rather in a streaming fashion. I tested that a query returning 1841 integers only used 40 TCP packets (and this including the "preparation queries" done by the driver).

Comment: @lapo I don't know the ins-and-outs of the MySQL protocol, but it is possible it changed, or the streaming is server side, and the MySQL driver itself will pick them one-by-one out of the stream (one on each `next()`), which would explain the caveat that you must read all rows before executing another statement on the same connection.

Comment: Using `OFFSET` will cause its own problems, possibly worse than the ones in the original question: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Answer (score 28):

If you enable the [MySQL JDBC option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) `useCursorFetch`, fetchSize will indeed be respected by the driver.

However, there is one disadvantage to this approach: It will use server-side cursors, which in MySQL are implemented using temporary tables. This will mean that results will not arrive until the query has been completed on the server, and that additional memory will be used server-side.

If you just want to use result streaming and don't care about the exact fetch size, the overhead of `setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` is not as bad as the docs might imply. It actually just disables client-side caching of the entire response and gives you responses as they arrive; there is no round-trip per row required.

Comment: Good answer.  Could you point toward any documentation to back up your assertion that no round trip is required?  Seems to me that would require some kind of background thread anyway..

Comment: With MIN_VALUE, MySQL seems to rely on the underlying TCP socket's flow control. As long as the receive window is reasonably sized (and all modern OSes do that by default), you should never have to wait for more data except if your read is bandwidth-limited in the first place.

Comment: when you say client side caching alone is disabled I am assuming that all the results of the query are still loaded into memory at once and the client just gets it one at a time. Is it right?

Comment: No, the results should really arrive as they are streamed by the server. I tested this with a long-running query that takes some minutes to complete otherwise: With MIN_VALUE, results start coming in after a much shorter initial wait.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to the above question. As I could not fit it in comment, I went to provide it as an answer. It may prove helpful to some facing a similar issue.

For a batch job, I needed to switch on the streaming mode as my result set was too large. At first, as seen in the MySQL [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), I set my connection up this way:

```
Statement extrapackStreamingQuery = dbExtrapackConnection.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); 
extrapackStreamingQuery.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

But it would systematically give me the error:

```
Application was streaming results when the connection failed. Consider raising value of 'net_write_timeout' on the server.
```

I did try a few configuration options, like: `max_allowed_packet = 128M`, `max_connect_errors = 9999` and `net_write_timeout = 180`. But none of them helped.

Wrongly thinking the TCP connection could be closed for being idle too long, I even tried changing the TCP ping time frame with a: `net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60` in the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time` and `/etc/sysctl.conf` files.

Indeed, if a database connection is opened but no TCP packets are sent for long enough, then the database connection will be lost as the TCP connection is closed. Sending TCP packets more often to keep the TCP connection alive may solve the issue.

But this didn't help either.

Then, after reading this [piece](https://github.com/ontop/ontop/wiki/WorkingWithMySQL) I change my connection setup to:

```
protected static final int DB_STREAMING_FETCH_AMOUNT = 50;
...
Statement extrapackStreamingQuery = dbExtrapackConnection.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);    
extrapackStreamingQuery.setFetchSize(DB_STREAMING_FETCH_AMOUNT);
```

with my url using a trailing option:

```
String fullUrl = url + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
if (streaming) {
    fullUrl += "?useCursorFetch=true";
}
```

My batch job is now working fine, it completes and even runs faster.