# Getting data from a very large table

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc, producer-consumer

I have a very large table in a MySQL database, 200 million records in table `Users`.

I make query, using JDBC:

```
public List<Pair<Long, String>> getUsersAll() throws SQLException {
        Connection cnn = null;
        CallableStatement cs = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        final List<Pair<Long, String>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            cnn = dataSource.getConnection();
            cs = cnn.prepareCall("select UserPropertyKindId, login from TEST.users;");
            rs = cs.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                res.add(new ImmutablePair<>(rs.getLong(1), rs.getString(2)));
            }
            return res;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(cnn, cs, rs);
        }
    }
```

Next, I process the result:

```
List<Pair<Long, String>> users= dao.getUsersAll();
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(users)) {
                for (List<Pair<Long, String>> partition : Lists.partition(users, 2000)) {
                    InconsistsUsers.InconsistsUsersCallable callable = new InconsistsUsers.InconsistsUsersCallable (new ArrayList<>(partition));
                    processExecutor.submit(callable);
                }
            }
```

But since the table is very large and it is all unloaded into memory, my application crashes with an error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 105,619 milliseconds ago.

How can I receive data in parts and process them in order of priority, so as not to upload all the result into memory at once? It may be possible to create a cursor and upload data to a non-blocking queue and process it as the data arrives. How can this be done?

**UPDATE:**

My DB structure: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v377ZHkG1YZcdQsETtPm9L/3

Current algorithm:

1. Get all data users from `Users` table: `select UserPropertyKindId, login from Users;`
2. This result is split for 2000 pairs and submit to `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`:

   ```
   List<Pair<Long, String>> users= dao.getUsersAll();

   if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(users)) {
       for (List<Pair<Long, String>> partition : Lists.partition(users, 2000)) {
           InconsistsUsers.InconsistsUsersCallable callable = new InconsistsUsers.InconsistsUsersCallable(new ArrayList<>(partition));
           processExecutor.submit(callable));
       }
   }
   ```
3. In callable for each pair make two queries:

   First query:

   ```
   select distinct entityId 
   from UserPropertyValue 
   where userPropertyKindId= ? and value = ? -- value its login from Users table
   ```

   Second query:

   ```
   select UserIds 
   from UserPropertyIndex 
   where UserPropertyKindId = ? and Value = ?
   ```

Two cases are possible:

1. Result of first query is empty: logging, send notification, continue to next pair
2. Result of second query is not equal to the result of the first query (varbinary data decoded. There are stored encoded entityId's). Then logging, send notification, go to next pair.

I can't change the structure of the base. All the manipulations I have to do on the Java code side.

Comment: you are facing query timeout issue, consider increasing the same

Comment: **Don't save all the users in memory**

Comment: @user7294900, I know, it's not right. But I don't know how to do otherwise

Comment: @All_Safe what are you trying to achieve? why holding 200 million records in memory?

Comment: @user7294900,For each user received from this table, you need to perform a certain processing and verification

Comment: i still wondering what you are trying to do here.. in a answer comment you are telling you want to compare data between multiple tables.. in MySQL you can JOIN the tables and compare between tables on the MySQL server..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Now the logic is. All data from the TEST table is unloaded.users. The pairs are then split into 2,000 elements and sent to a separate thread for processing. The following happens in the stream: for each pair <login, password> two queries are made to the tables. Further, two options are possible. The result of the first table is empty, a certain logic is Made, an entry in the log, notification of the administrator. The result of the selection from the first table is not equal to the second. Another entry is made in the log. Otherwise miss.

Comment: "The following happens in the stream: for each pair <login, password> two queries are made to the tables." wierd approach so the application would fire 400 million queries for the 200 million users assuming the application could hold 200 million users in memory. Time to show the database structure some example data on sqlfiddle or db-fiddle (note don't post real user password hashes there), And explain the results you need and make a formatted text output..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I updated my question.See please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should handle this on several levels:

#### JDBC driver fetch size

JDBC has a [`Statement.setFetchSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)) method, which indicates how many rows are going to be pre-fetched by the JDBC driver prior to you getting them from JDBC. Note that MySQL JDBC drivers don't really implement this correctly, but you can set `setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` to prevent it from fetching all rows in one go. [See also this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26053667/521799).

Note, you may also activate the feature on your connection using [`useCursorFetch`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

#### Your own logic

You should not put the entire list of users in memory. What you're doing right now is collecting all the rows from JDBC and then partitioning your list later on using `Lists.partition(users, 2000)`. This is going in the right direction, but you're not doing it right yet. Instead, do:

```java
try (ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery()) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        res.add(new ImmutablePair<>(rs.getLong(1), rs.getString(2)));
    }

    // Process a batch of rows:
    if (res.size() >= 2000) {
        process(res);
        res.clear();
    }
}

// Process the remaining rows
process(res);
```

The important message here is to not load all rows in memory *and then* process them in batches, but to process them directly while streaming rows from JDBC.

Comment: When I write: `setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)`, I will come from the database 1 line? As far as I understand, it is not possible to specify the size of the part  in `MySQL`, it ignores it

Comment: @All_Safe: Yes, MySQL doesn't support fetching N rows at a time, only all rows or row by row

Comment: Say please, If I will be used `useCursorFetch=true`, I need set this params: `stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
              java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);` ? Or enough this: `stmt.setFetchSize(2000);` ?

Comment: `setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)`. Observe: `MIN_VALUE`. I've linked to older Stack Overflow questions explaining why `MIN_VALUE` needs to be used in MySQL

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Lists.partition(users, 2000) in Java side, you should limit your mysql resultset to 2000 per request.

```
select UserPropertyKindId, login from TEST.users limit <offset>, 2000;
```

Update: as mentioned by Raymond Nijland in the comment below, if the offset is too large, the query could be significantly slowed down.

One workaround could be instead of using offset, introduce a where statement such as where id > last_user_id.

Since @All_safe commented below, an autoincrement id doesn't exist, another workaround for the large limit offset is that: fetch the primary key only in subquery and then join back to main table. This will force mysql to not do early rows lookup, which is the main problem of large offset limit.

But your original query only fetch primary key columns, I don't think early rows lookups applies.

Comment: I suppose in this case, there will be a lot of queries to the database

Comment: Yes, you are talking about  200 million records. No of queries is not the main concern here.

Comment: I did not understand a phrase: "No of queries is not the main concern here"

Comment: 1. You are trying to get 200 millions records in one query and storing all in memory, I don't think it's a good idea. 2. What you will do in your loop processing of each records? Will you update database? 3. If this is a batch job, maybe you can consider sqldump and then a java application to process on the dump data, instead of hitting database. Again, avoid loading all to memory.

Comment: I won't update the database. For each user, I need to pull the data from the other two tables and compare them.

Comment: Couple off problems with this approach.. First limit with large offset values will slow down the query execution huge.. `limit 1000000, 2000` MySQL needs to fetch 1002000 records and probably needs to use a temporary table to handle the results the higher the number the more it slows down.. Second SQL tables are unorderd data. SQL will not guarantee running the query `select login, password from TEST.users limit 0, 2000;` multiple times will result in the same results you also need to use a `ORDER BY` then SQL guarantees the same results always.

Comment: This should be able to be resolved if the Users table have an autoincrement id,so the query can where user_id > last_value order by the id asc.

Comment: @Jacob, unfortunately the table does not have an autoincrement column

Comment: The problem with limit large offset is caused by mysql early rows lookup and another workaround is that you can have a subquery to fetch the primary key first with order by and join back to the main table.

Comment: Updated the answer, after checking your schema.  your original query only fetch primary key columns, I don't think large offset issue will applied to your first query

Comment: Please don't use offset pagination on very large tables! https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Comment: @LukasEder UserPropertyKindId, login are composite keys, so that it won't suffer from the early rows loopkup which caused the slow limit. My original answer seems problematic , but after OP has changed its query, limit shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Jacob: I'm not referring to `LIMIT`, which is hardly ever a problem. I'm referring to `OFFSET`

Comment: @LukasEder Yes, large offset is problematic, but since then OP has changed the query to return indexed column only, is large offset still a problem?

Comment: @Jacob: Yes of course it is still a problem. The index has to be scanned sequentially to count the exact number of rows to skip. I mean, this makes it a bit less of a problem but still a big one. And the query is run many times. Click on the link I provided, it explains it very well :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar situation. I'm reading data from a a MySQL DB and copy it into an MS SQL Server DB. Not 200Million, only 4 Millions a day. But I had the same error message with the communication link failure. I could solve it by setting the fetchsize of the PreparedStatement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE); 
So the communication link failure disappeared. I know, this does not solve your list problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can bake your priority into the query 
e.g., `WHERE my_priority = 1 ORDER BY my_sub_priority DESC`

AND LIKE Jacob said, use limits `LIMIT 0, 2000`

You can probably break up the logic in inconsistent_users to look for specific defects and then optimize those queries with insights gained in EXPLAIN. Maybe a find_user_defect(defect) kind of approach will help you process users setwise.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create jdbcTemplate, set it's fetchSize property which is important for processing large result sets.

```
jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(50000);
```