# Writing Data from RDS to Disk in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

My use case is that I have to run a query on RDS instance and it returns 2 millions records. Now,I want to copy the result directly to disk instead of bringing it in memory then copying it to disk.

Following statement will bring all the records in memory, I want to transfer the results directly to file on disk.

```
SelectQuery<Record> abc = dslContext.selectQuery().fetch();
```

Can anyone suggest an pointer?

**Update1:**
I found the following way to read it :

```java
try (Cursor<BookRecord> cursor = create.selectFrom(BOOK).fetchLazy()) {
    while (cursor.hasNext()){
        BookRecord book = cursor.fetchOne();
        Util.doThingsWithBook(book);
    }
}
```

How many records does it fetch at once and are those records brought in memory first?

**Update2:**
MySQL driver by default it fetches all the records at once. If fetch size is set to Integer.MIN_VALUE then it fetches one record at a time. If you want to fetch the records in batches then set useCursorFetch=true while setting connection properties.
Related wiki : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html

Comment: i'm assuming "RDS" is `Amazon RDS` (correct me, otherwise). at first glance, it appears your question is "how can you read data from a cloud database instance and write the results directly to disk without passing through memory?"... but, given the amount of expected data, are you actually asking how to avoid fetching the entire resultset at once, and instead read it in chunks? (ie paging)

Comment: Yes I am talking about Amazon Aurora. Yes I don't have to do any processing on the result sets, I just have to write it on disk. Yes I want to read it in chunks but will these chunk as well come in memory first?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach using the [`ResultQuery.fetchLazy()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchLazy--) method is the way to go for jOOQ to fetch records one at a time from JDBC. Note that you can use [`Cursor.fetchNext(int)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Cursor.html#fetchNext-int-) to fetch a batch of records from JDBC as well.

There's a second thing you might need to configure, and that's the JDBC fetch size, see [`Statement.setFetchSize(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)). This configures how many rows are fetched by the JDBC driver from the server in a single batch. Depending on your database / JDBC driver (e.g. MySQL), the default would again be to fetch all rows in one go. In order to specify the JDBC fetch size on a jOOQ query, use [`ResultQuery.fetchSize(int)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchSize-int-). So your loop would become:

```
try (Cursor<BookRecord> cursor = create
        .selectFrom(BOOK)
        .fetchSize(size)
        .fetchLazy()) {
    while (cursor.hasNext()){
        BookRecord book = cursor.fetchOne();
        Util.doThingsWithBook(book);
    }
}
```

Please read your JDBC driver manual about how they interpret the fetch size, [noting that MySQL is "special"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26046234/521799)