# Does SQL cursor use less memory?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, cursor

In this code:

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con, String dbName)
    throws SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    String query =
        "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, " +
        "SALES, TOTAL " +
        "from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
            int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
            float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
            int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
            int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
            System.out.println(coffeeName + "\t" + supplierID +
                               "\t" + price + "\t" + sales +
                               "\t" + total);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}
```

In particular, this code:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Does this statement retrieve all rows to ResultSet, or partly? I need to load a table with 5 million rows in Hibernate and there is an OutofMemory error. It fails on this line:

```
List<Term> terms = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

I need to find a way in Mysql & Hibernate to load this table with a memory issue. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need all those records in memory?

Comment: @juergend: It looks from the question as though the answer to that is very much "no", but Hibernate is loading the full resultset into memory on `Statement.executeQuery()`.

Comment: I may not need to load into memory with the full table, but just curious to know whether there is a better way to do that.

Comment: What I have found is that people that bring in all the data into arrays need to take tutorials on db use. Not the least of which reason is data staleness.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA: what is the proper pattern for iterating over large result sets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067619/jpa-what-is-the-proper-pattern-for-iterating-over-large-result-sets)

Comment: Generally in Production enviornment Pool size is greater and virtual memory allocated is also more than normal in Dev environment. So better limit the size for optimization.

Comment: Also you can use `criteria.setMaxSize(50);`