# Running Cobertura with PowerMockito throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, maven, powermock, cobertura, powermockito

How to solve the **Out of memory** / **PermGen space** issue while using [powermockito](/questions/tagged/powermockito) + [cobertura](/questions/tagged/cobertura).
When I ran `mvn cobertura:cobertura` on test cases it's getting exception like below:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(Mock
ClassLoader.java:250)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(Mock
ClassLoader.java:194)
        at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(D
eferSupportingClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ProjectData.getOrCreateClassDa
ta(ProjectData.java:88)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector.applyTouchesOnP
rojectData(TouchCollector.java:109)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ProjectData.saveGlobalProjectD
ata(ProjectData.java:272)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.SaveTimer.run(SaveTimer.java:3
3)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ProjectData.addClassData(Proje
ctData.java:64)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ProjectData.getOrCreateClassDa
ta(ProjectData.java:89)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector.applyTouchesOnP
rojectData(TouchCollector.java:109)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.ProjectData.saveGlobalProjectD
ata(ProjectData.java:272)
        at net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.SaveTimer.run(SaveTimer.java:3
3)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Thread-22" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-24" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-25" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I tried by adding max memory by using below cobertura property as mentioned in [cobertura-mojo](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/cobertura-mojo.html#maxmem):

```
<cobertura.maxmem>1024m</cobertura.maxmem>
```

but it's not working as expected, 
I can see there are few open issues [Issue-227](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/227), [Issue-520](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/520) at [PowerMock repository](https://github.com/jayway/powermock), 
I try to add ignore packages by using below annotation but it's not working if number of test classes are more. `@PowerMockIgnore({"com.package.*"})`

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
     </build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx1624m</argLine>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                <!--<argLine>-Xmx600m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError</argLine> -->
                <forkCount>10</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
            <quiet>true</quiet>
            <cobertura.maxmem>1024m</cobertura.maxmem>
                <instrumentation>
                    <maxmem>1024m</maxmem>
                </instrumentation>
                <!-- <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine> -->
                <!-- <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine> -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <phase>pre-site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>instrument</id>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>instrument</goal>
                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
     .......
    </plugins>
  </build>

 <reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- using mvn cobertura:cobertura to generate cobertura reports -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Please let me know if there is any workaround for this.

Comment: Are you using surefire plugin ?

Comment: @Santosh, Yes. by adding or without adding surefire plugin there is no difference. getting same issue.

Comment: can you show the full stack trace..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add **`<version>2.19.1</version>`** to `maven-surefire-plugin` in pom.xml, it should work fine.

```
            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                 <argLine>-Xmx1624m</argLine>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            </configuration>
           </plugin>
```

Comment: Yes You are correct @Praveen Kumar, when I added the version number to maven-surefire-plugin, I am able to run all the tests without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

I want to give you some suggestions to solve the issue.

1. First remove all memory space from your pom.xml.
2. Secondly, increase your JVM options `"-XX:PermSize"` and `"-XX:MaxPermSize"` based on your project need.

### Root Cause Analysis:

- `JVM default size of Perm Space is around "64MB"` you can easily ran
  out of memory if you have too many classes or huge number of Strings
  in your project. **Important point to remember is that it doesn't
  depends on -Xmx value so no matter how big your total heap size you
  can ran OutOfMemory in perm space.** Good think is you can specify
  size of permanent generation using JVM options `"-XX:PermSize"` and
  `"-XX:MaxPermSize"` based on your project need.
- Another reason of `"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen"` is memory
  leak through Classloaders and it's very often surfaced in WebServer
  and application server like tomcat, webshere, glassfish or weblogic.
- Another reason of OutOfMemoryError in PermGen space is if any thread 
  started by application doesn't exit when you undeploy your
  application.

  ```
  JVM_ARGS="-XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
  ```

  where

  `-XX:PermSize<size> - Set initial PermGen Size.`

  `-XX:MaxPermSize<size> - Set the maximum PermGen Size.`

### Resource Link:

1. [Tomcat – java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/)
2. [Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/dealing-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Answer (score 2):

As @Alexander mentioned, the problem you have is that you are running out of Permanent Generation space (Memory area that stores static objects, class info, etc. ). The  and -Xmx settings deal with the Heap space.

You want to Set the MaxPermSize, like @Alexander mentioned:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Another option is to upgrade to JDK 8, which does away with the Permanent Generation all together, in favor of MetaSpace.

[Memory Model Management in Java](http://www.journaldev.com/2856/java-jvm-memory-model-memory-management-in-java)

[Java PermGen Removed](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-PERMGEN-Removed)

Answer (score 0):

Just uncomment the line with `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` in your **pom.xml**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in a web project using glassfish server. This was because I was reading the whole table which contains about 600000 rows of data with about 50 columns at once. I finally resolve the issue by reading by batch fetching, this did not only solve the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen` space error but also improved on the performance greatly.

May be you are in the same shoes, and if that's the case even if you increase the perm size to 4096 you will still get the same issue sometime in the future.

You can check: [JPA: what is the proper pattern for iterating over large result sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067619/jpa-what-is-the-proper-pattern-for-iterating-over-large-result-sets) to see how it is implemented in jpa.