# Obtaining JPA Session in Spring Boot Scheduler

Tags: spring, session, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-scheduled

In my Spring Boot Webapp I have a scheduler class with @EnableScheduling
and @EnableAsync running at night by @Scheduled. The class is obtaining a session with:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

which results in this exception:

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
```

What is the correct way to obtain a session for scheduled tasks?

Here is the following code:

```
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT l FROM Lei l ORDER BY l.id");
        query.setFetchSize(Integer.valueOf(1000));
        query.setReadOnly(true);
        query.setLockMode("a", LockMode.NONE);
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067619/jpa-what-is-the-proper-pattern-for-iterating-over-large-result-sets
        ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
        while (results.next()) {
            Lei lei = (Lei) results.get(0);
            writer.writeLEI(lei);
        }
        results.close();
        session.close();
```

Comment: can you post some more code?

Comment: Why would you need the `Session`... What i wrong with using a plain `EntityManager`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test service I just created ( I'm using spring boot 1.4 with all the default configuration ):

```
@Service
public class ScheduledService {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 500L)
    @Transactional
    private void reportCurrentTime() {
        entityManager = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        System.out.println(session.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Then I can see the session hashcode in the console

```
1410300721
966623925
181180995
1606490891
1882727729
635804073
1259672020
484131582
```

Comment: I can also display the hashCode, but then I exeute a query I get the exception above

Comment: Executing a query in your example works for me. Now I need to figure out why it does not work in my project

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Stupid me! I closed the session

session.close();